# using conditions in panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this my data frame
[my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPj15.png)
i use this code to get something called WT

```
DF['T.U']=DF['WIDE']*DF['LENGTH']*DF['QTY']/1000000+DF['CLAD_THK']*DF['LENGTH']*DF['QTY']/1000000
    DF['U.W']=DF['THK']*78.5/10 + DF['CLAD_THK']*79.9/10
    DF['W.T']=DF['T.U']*DF['U.W']
    DF['W.T']=DF['WT']/1000
```

this is how data is after applying code
[data frame after code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOWX6.png)
I want to add conditions depending on the MAT column to calculate WT for example if i have MAT=516, apply this code

```
 DF['T.U']=DF['WIDE']*DF['LENGTH']*DF['QTY']/1000000+DF['CLAD_THK']*DF['LENGTH']*DF['QTY']/1000000
 DF['U.W']=DF['THK']*78.5/10 + DF['CLAD_THK']*79.9/10
 DF['W.T']=DF['T.U']*DF['U.W']
 DF['W.T']=DF['WT']/1000
```

if MAT=240 apply this

```
DF['T.U']=DF['WIDE']*DF['LENGTH']*DF['QTY']/1000000+DF['CLAD_THK']*DF['LENGTH']*DF['QTY']/1000000
DF['U.W']=DF['THK']*79.9/10 + DF['CLAD_THK']*79.9/10
DF['W.T']=DF['T.U']*DF['U.W']
DF['W.T']=DF['WT']/1000
```

Comment: Please do not post a picture of your data set. You should provide a reproducible sample of your data so that others could use it to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over rows on your dataframe:

```
for index, row in DF.iterows():
   if (row['MAT'] == 516):
       # Apply code 1 on row instead of DF
   elif (row['MAT'] == 240):
       # Apply code 2 on row instead of DF
```